# How do I modify my arrayList as I enter it into another arrayList such that to remove and change it's values?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have made an array list that stores words from a text file. but now I need to make a separate array list that only takes the letters from the words in the file reverts them to lower case and removes all punctuation in the words or around it. So basically it restores all the words with all the mentioned elements removed from them.

```
        List<String> grams = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String gram : words){
            gram = gram.trim();
            for(int i=0,int l=gram.size();i<l;++i){ //this line is wrong
                const String punChars = ",[]:'-!_().?\/~"; //this line is wrong
                if(gram.indexOf(i) != -1){ //this line is wrong
                    gram.remove(i); //this line is wrong
                }
                gram.add(gram.remove(0).toLowerCase()); //this line is wrong
            }
        }
```

I'm basically trying to read each character in a select string in the array as I put it into the new array list and then if it has any punctuation around or in it I remove it: I try to do this using a const to store the punctuation values and then I check the string with an if statement to remove that position in the string.

Next I try and add the word but remove the uppercase and change it to lowercase.

I'm a little lost and am not sure what I am doing with this bit here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of your problem is that you want to go through a list of words, convert them into lowercase, remove punctuation and then insert them into another list? If that's the case, then I don't see why you need to modify the original list. You can do something like this:

```
for(String gram : words) {
    gram = gram.trim(); //trim string
    gram = gram.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""); //remove any non alphanumeric characters
    grams.add(gram); //add to the grams list
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vivian, this method effectively removes all the punctuation and is a much simpler method that I am almost embarrassed that I didn't think of in the first place. I am going to attempt to complete the rest of my question however, which was switching all the uppercase to lowercase. I am going to attempt to simply use this replace all method for that as well.

Comment: OK SO I DID THIS AND IT WAS DUMB. So instead I just tried 
gram = gram.toLowerCase(); and it worked. Thank you so much for your help aside.

Comment: @RyanTibbetts I missed the part where you had to convert it to lowercase. Yes, so doing that should work!

Answer (score 0):

Why not cycle through each character in the String like this:

```
for (char c : gram.toCharArray()) {
  ...
}
```

Then check to see if your character is in list of excluded characters and if not then lower case it and add it to your output list?